# How to make text show up in a specific location on a Tkinter window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label, tkinter-text

please see the code below. Working on a 100 days of code project. How to I make text appear in a specific position (x=400, y=150) for example on a window.

Please see my code below.

```Python
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#B1DDC6"

window = Tk()
window.title('Flashy')
window.config(padx=50, pady=50, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR)

# Todo. Center the front of the card.

canvas = Canvas(width=800, height=526, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR, highlightthickness=0)
card_front = PhotoImage(file='images/card_front.png')
canvas.create_image(400, 263, image=card_front)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)

# Placing text on the card.
text_1 = Label(text="French", bg='white', font=("Ariel", 40, "italic"), fg='black')
text_1.goto(x=400, y=150)
text_1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

# Buttons
check_mark = PhotoImage(file='images/right.png')
check_mark_button = Button(image=check_mark, highlightthickness=0)
check_mark_button.grid(row=1, column=2)

wrong_mark = PhotoImage(file='images/wrong.png')
wrong_mark_button = Button(image=wrong_mark, highlightthickness=0)
wrong_mark_button.grid(row=1, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

I tried using .config to specify the location for the text but that doesn't work.

Comment: I think you may have a typo - `font=("Ariel" ...` is probably supposed to be `font=("Arial" ...`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `place()` geometry manager to [place](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-place/) widgets at specific coordinates.

Instead of:

```
text_1.goto(x=400, y=150)
```

Try...

```
text_1.place(x=400, y=150)
```

And remove:

```
text_1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

since you should only use one geometry manager method (`pack`, `grid`, or `place`) on a given widget.